# Dividing not adjacent cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Any suggestions of how to solve this problem?

(Updated)

`numerator`,`denominator` are ranges containing integer values.

I want to do a division cell by cell of these ranges, e.g:

```
numerator(1)/denominator(1) numerator(2)/denominator(2) ...
```

and paste the results in `quotient`. All ranges are of same size and are row-vector dimensioned.

My solution attempt:

```
Sub DivRanges()
    Dim targetRng As Range, sourceRng1 As Range, sourceRng2 As Range    
    For i = 1 To targetRng.Cells.Count
         quotient.Cells(i).Value = numerator.Cells(i).Value / denominator.Cells(i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that `DivRanges` doesn't loop through each value of the ranges since they are row-vectors. Instead it goes horisontally one step down as i grows. This problem occurs when the cells of the ranges are **not adjacent.**

Here's a display of the problem based on code from mehow . The result are the cells selected in the sheet.

[image: Example]

Comment: row-vectors? what do they look like in a cell? Can you provide a screenshot or sample? is there a few values in a single cell? please explain

Comment: +1 for updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your spreadsheet looks like

[image: bef]

then this code

```
Sub DivRanges()
    Dim quotient As Range, numerator As Range, denominator As Range
    
    Set numerator = Range("A1:D1")
    Set denominator = Range("A2:D2")
    Set quotient = Range("A3:D3")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To quotient.Count
        quotient.Cells(i).Value = numerator.Cells(i).Value / denominator.Cells(i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

gives you

[image: aft]

***<kbd>Update</kbd>***

## Not adjacent Cells solution

assuming your sheet

[image: before]

using the below code

```
Sub DivRanges()
    Dim quotient As Range, numerator As Range, denominator As Range

    Set numerator = Range("A1, C1, D1, E1")
    Set denominator = Range("A2, C2, D2, E2")
    Set quotient = Range("A3, C3, D3, E3")
    
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    For Each c In quotient
        Range(c.Address) = Range(getNum(numerator.Address, i)) / Range(getNum(denominator.Address, i))
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
End Sub

Function getNum(str As String, i As Long) As String
    getNum = Split(str, ",")(i)
End Function
```

result is

[image: result]

Comment: You are correct. But the cells are not adjacent in my case and this  causes the problem. I'll add this in the description.

Comment: @karamell oh I see man! I have updates my answer please let me know if that's what you were looking for